# how can i summarize some data in a MySQL table based on subsets of data determined by a datetime field?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum, pivot

Lets say i have this table:

```
id  name        date              qty
1 bananas 2020-04-01 00:00:00     20
2 apples  2020-04-02 00:00:00     15
3 apples  2020-04-05 00:00:00     15
4 bananas 2020-04-06 00:00:00     10
5 bananas 2020-04-15 00:00:00     40
6 bananas 2020-04-16 00:00:00     20
7 apples  2020-04-17 00:00:00     15
8 apples  2020-04-17 00:00:00      5
```

What i want to achieve is a result set with total quantity of each fruit before 2020-04-06 in a InitialStock field and total quantity of each fruit after 2020-04-17 as FinalStock

Comment: Please show us the results that you expect.

Comment: You have no rows after 2020-04-17, unless you mean "on or after".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select
    name, 
    sum(case when date <= '2020-04-06' then qty end) initial_stock,
    sum(case when date >= '2020-04-17' then qty end) final_stock
from mytable
group by name
```

For each `name`, this gives you the sum of `qty` before April 4th and after Apri 17th, in two separated columns.